# MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR

Tags: sql-server

My server started running very slowly and when I looked at the sql server logs I saw below message

AppDomain is marked for unload due to memory pressure

When I ran the below query

server is - sql server 2016 with 64 GB memory

select * from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks where type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR'

It returned below 2 rows. (Assuming if it returned rows it is a problem)

[image: Query Results]

I rebooted the server, Restarted the SQL server services I am still getting the below 2 rows and my queries are still running very slow. Can you please advise me on how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think this specific clerk is related to your slow queries? I see this error log entry on a lot of servers but that doesn't mean it is causing queries to be slow. Your server has 64 GB of memory, what are min/max server memory settings for SQL Server? Are you intentionally using any custom or built-in CLR functionality?

Comment: I have 0 min and 52GB max as my memory settings. I really assumed it may be related to slow queries/memory issues. I don't have enough knowledge as a DBA and I am a backup DBA.

Comment: You'll need to take a query that is slow and analyze why it is slow. What is it waiting on when it's running? Is it being blocked? What does the execution plan look like? Also, according to Brent, [your max server memory should be 58982 MB](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/max-memory/). That's 6 GB more SQL Server can use.

Comment: I changed the memory to 58982MB changed the query to use Join instead of Intersect and it ran in 1 min. (It was taking 44 minutes before) I ran the old query with intersect and it ran in 1 min. I haven't changed anything else. I don't know what fixed the issue I was experiencing.